# Backup to NAS or Cloud

Tags: backup, symantec, online-backup

Currently, we backup for all the servers daily using Symmetric Backup Executive 10D to a tape drive.  But now, we're considering changing the backup to either NAS or to cloud storage since the tape drive is giving me a lot of problems.

Can we backup to NAS or cloud storage using the existing Symmetric Backup Exec 10D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd Recommend both,

Yes both can be pricey but,

It's always good to have a backup on site as well as off site.

If there was a power outage that corrupted multiple files that were open at the time, you can quickly restore them from the NAS.

If there was a fire that destroys your NAS you can backup from the Cloud.

The more Back up Solutions the better especially if the Data is sensitive which I'm assuming it is.

A NAS is a once off payment of X amount, Cloud storage is X amount per month, you need to value your data, if you lost a backup how much would it cost the company? would you lose clients? would the company survive etc... after you value your data you can then decide which path you would like to take.

We use a program called Backup4ALL, supports NAS and cloud Backups, Simultaneously as well, it also supports AWS, Dropbox, Google Drive, so you have plenty of providers to choose from.

http://www.backup4all.com/

As for you question in regards to your current software, a quick read on there website if i'm looking at the correct one shows they support NAS and Cloud Backup, although that is for the latest version which seems to be 15.

https://www.veritas.com/en/uk/product/backup-and-recovery/backup-exec?om_sem_kw=backup%20exec%2010d&s_kwcid=AL!4649!3!100430979982!p!!g!!backup%20exec%2010d&CID=701j00000022c06AAAv&ef_id=VwKFkgAAAFqh6WcD:20160614155857:s

Answer (score 1):

If you can make sure you can manage your data disks safely then you can make a prefrences to NAS  there is to many openSource NAS is available like FreeNAS,NASforFree. These are all opensource for software nas if you prefer to go for Built-in NAS that is your wish. And if you can't maintain the NAS. I would kikes and prefers you to go for the Cloud Storage But I don't have any idea about cloud providers and try to prefer a good clod providers like amazon,google,azure so that you can't loose your data for sure.